# How to write String to file in FragmentStatePagerAdapter class

Tags: android, file

I want to write String to file in non-Activity class that extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

Any help?

My method where i want to write String to file file looks like this:

```
Context ctx;

public void saveFile() {
    String xmlString = "";
    for (int i=0; i<mNumOfTabs; i++) {
        xmlString += days[i].toString() + "\n";
    }

    try{
        FileOutputStream fOut = ctx.openFileOutput("config.txt", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);

        osw.write(xmlString);

        osw.flush();

        osw.close();
    }

    catch (IOException ioe)
    {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

And here is logcat:

```
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.FileOutputStream android.content.Context.openFileOutput(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
                                                                       at com.skolarac.skolarac.PageAdapter.saveFile(PageAdapter.java:78)
                                                                       at com.skolarac.skolarac.Day.onActivityResult(Day.java:165)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:164)
                                                                       at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6932)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4085)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4132) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1533) 
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                                       com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your Context is null.

To solve it you can add the context to your class constructor:

```
public class MyClass extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    Context ctx;
    public MyClass(Context context) { ctx = context;}

    ...
}
```

Comment: @Dooron Yakovlev-Golani  Thx this answer solved my problem